# Efficient method to preload larger images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, preload

I am building a site which is centered around a slide with a lot of large images. I wanted to preload these images so that users don't experience any loading or too much lag while browsing the site. I came across [this page](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) and decided to use JavaScript Method #1. So I basically followed the code given and put this in my footer, of course adding in my own images.

```
<div class="hidden">
    <script>
        <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
        var images = new Array()
        function preload() {
            for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image()
                images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
            }
        }
        preload(
            "/img/slides/bbq.jpg",
            "/img/slides/ext-avt-office.jpg",
            "/img/slides/ext-front-abstract.jpg",
            "/img/slides/ext-front-wide.jpg",
            "/img/slides/front-door.jpg",
            "/img/slides/glass-rill-2.jpg",
            "/img/slides/glass-rill.jpg",
            "/img/slides/kitchen-west.jpg",
            "/img/slides/koi-pond-day.jpg",
            "/img/slides/main-hall-2.jpg",
            "/img/slides/main-hall-wide.jpg",
            "/img/slides/master-bath.jpg",
            "/img/slides/master-doors-day.jpg",
            "/img/slides/pool-area.jpg",
            "/img/slides/pool-back-of-house.jpg",
            "/img/slides/rear-porch.jpg",
            "/img/slides/reglet-detail.jpg",
            "/img/slides/amythist-vanity.jpg",
            "/img/slides/art-and-statue.jpg",
            "/img/slides/avf-office-vanity.jpg",
            "/img/slides/bonsai-tree-night.jpg",
            "/img/slides/chandelier-detail.jpg",
            "/img/slides/childrens-vestibule.jpg",
            "/img/slides/detail-of-vanity-graff-valve.jpg",
            "/img/slides/dining-table.jpg",
            "/img/slides/front-door-detail.jpg",
            "/img/slides/garage-cabinetry.jpg",
            "/img/slides/guest-vanity-detail.jpg",
            "/img/slides/kitchen-waterfall-detail.jpg",
            "/img/slides/koi-pond-night-lantern.jpg",
            "/img/slides/library-angle.jpg",
            "/img/slides/library-bookcase.jpg",
            "/img/slides/meditation-room.jpg",
            "/img/slides/nautical-handrail-detail.jpg",
            "/img/slides/neon-love-seat.jpg",
            "/img/slides/office-bookcase-detail.jpg",
            "/img/slides/playboy-dining-chair-2.jpg",
            "/img/slides/playboy-dining-chair.jpg",
            "/img/slides/rearview-mirror-coffee-table.jpg",
            "/img/slides/westward-chair-close-up.jpg",
            "/img/slides/westward-chairs-and-couch.jpg"
        )
    //--><!]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

However, given the size of each of these images, it's really slowing down the site. PageSpeed gave me a score of 17 out of a 100 even after optimizing the images. The total mb of all of the images is 13.8. Before it was in the 50-some mb.

Are there more efficient ways to preload huge images like these? Here is the [live link](http://keebs.com/dax/).

Update:

So, here's what I decided to try out based on the marked answer below:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    function preload(imageArray, index) {
            index = index || 0;
            if (imageArray && imageArray.length > index) {
                var img = new Image ();
                img.onload = function() {
                    preload(imageArray, index + 1);
                }
                img.src = images[index]['serving_url'];
    }
    /* images is an array with image metadata */
    preload(images);
});

var images = [
    "image1.jpg",
    "image2.jpg",
    "image3.jpg"
];
```

I'm just confused what goes in the `serving_url` area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this you really want to prioritize which images load based on user behavior. If it's a slider you have a pretty good idea which images(s) will be needed first.

If you create a loop and add `src` attributes to all the image objects at once, the browser will try to download a bunch of images concurrently, which means the one you need right away could take a really long time. If you want to preload the whole gallery, it is better in cases like this to download sequentially.

Here's a recent article about this exact issue with code examples:

http://www.photo-mark.com/notes/image-preloading/

Comment: So I read the article and I'm guessing that if I use sequential preloading, I'd have to put all of the images in the order that I want into an array. Is that correct? Would I have to rename them to 001, 002, 003, etc?

Comment: Yes, you will want to specify the order of loading in a way that fits their mostly likely use otherwise it defeats the purpose. You don't need to rename the files, however. You can simply put them in an array in the order you want them to load and then go through them sequentially: `var images = ['firstUrl, 'anotherUrl', …]`

Comment: Thanks, just one question. What goes in the `serving_url` area? I updated my question above.

Comment: I suppose I could make that more clear in the piece. I am using an array of objects I get from the server called images. It has a bunch of metadata for the images including the url for the image. 

`var images = [{title: "first img", serving_url: "http://foo.bar"}, {title: "next img", …]`

So then as I loop though I can get the url by asking for `images[i]['serving_url']`.  With the code you have, you could just use `img.src = images[index]`

Comment: Thanks, @MarkM. That makes it a bit more clear for someone new like myself. So would you advise creating the array in PHP and passing it to the JS function? What would be the advantage of this as opposed to creating the array directly underneath the function in JS?

Comment: I am passing the info in from the server as a JSON object because it's easier. I can just serialize the database object and send it over. All the info is in a database and I don't want it hard-coded into the page. This allows me to to add an image to the database on the backend and have the site reflect the update without having to mess around with the HTML templates. It also lets me pass in other data like captions that I can update as the images swap out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to preload them all.

How many images can you see at once? Preload only those first few.

Then once the site loads, start loading the next ones in order.

Your site will load much faster. As a general rule of thumb, for initial page load, only load the assets you need for it to render properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait the page to be load before preload.

```
Window.onload = function (){

  //preload

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slideshow should preload only the first slide and the adjacent slides. When the slides change, check if the next (and previous) slide is preloaded and load it if not. If it was not loaded, make your transition wait for it to load, if it is loaded, cycle normally.

Comment: What you said makes perfect sense, but I wouldn't know where to start with coding something like that. I'm fairly new to all of this. If you know of any tutorials or articles that might help, or even search terms, it would help.

Comment: This might be a quick solution for you then: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-lazy-load/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Also, I was just doing some searching and I found a solution here that sounds like what you mentioned. Is this along the lines of what you had in mind? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12535936/1536869

Comment: That looks like it would work pretty well. You could take it a step further and lazy load as previously described to save bandwidth on page bounces or brief visits, but that should pretty much resolve the initial loading issue.